# ruby access non-vowels of a string in condition line without arrays

Tags: ruby, string, conditional-statements

I need to turn a string that contains (among other letters) a sequence of 3 letters consisting of a non-vowel, an "o" and the same non-vowel again
into 
a string that contains (other letters and) only that non-vowel.

like

```
"kok" #=> "k"
"mom" #=> "m"
"lol" #=> "l"
"kokmomloljk" #=> "kmljk"
```

I would like my code to be as compact as possible and only use string methods.

```
str.each_char { | i | if i == /[^aeiou]/ and i == str[i.index + 2] and str[i.index + 1] == "o"
str = str.delete(str.slice(str[i.index + 1], 2))
end
}
```

The output is the unchanged string. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R = /
    ([^aeiou]) # match a consonant in capture group 1
    o          # match an 'o'
    \1         # match the contents of capture group 1
    /x         # free-spacing regex definition mode

def my_method(str)   
  str.gsub(R,'\1')
end

my_method "my dog kok has fleas"
  #=> "my dog k has fleas" 
my_method "much momentum"
  #=> "much mentum" 
my_method "'plolly' is not a word"
  #=> "'plly' is not a word" 
my_method "abkokcmomloljkde"
  #=> "abkcmljkde" 
my_method "bub"
  #=> "bub"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if you could do this in a more functional non-destructieve way with `map` and, yes you can, but not more compact than the other answers:

```
str = "iskakmomlol"
VOWEL    = /[aeiou]/
RESONANT = /[^aeiou]/
str.chars.map.with_index { |c, i| 
  prevb, prev, nxt, scnd = str[i - 2], str[i - 1], str[i + 1], str[i + 2]
  if i > str.length - 1 || i == 0 then c
  elsif c =~ RESONANT && nxt =~ VOWEL && c == scnd then c
  elsif c =~ VOWEL && prev =~ RESONANT && nxt =~ RESONANT
  elsif c =~ RESONANT && prevb == c && prev =~ VOWEL
  else  c
  end
}.compact.join # "iskmljk"
```

---

Actually, this can be shorter:

```
R = /([^aeiou])[aeiou]\1/
str.chars.map.with_index { |c, i| 
  c unless str[i-1..i+1][R] || str[i-2..i][R]
}.compact.join # "iskmljk"
```

Comment: If `str = "kokok"` this returns `"kk"`. I don't know if the asker wants that or `"kok"`. dongo?

Comment: yes, my edit handles that as one k, if desired is up to dongo, by combining our answers he should be able to get what he wants

Comment: the sequence of "kok" should be accepted and turned into "k" before the rest of the string is read, so "kokkok" returns "kk" and "kokok" returns "kok".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, dongo. Two points. 1. It's best to make clarifications by editing your question, rather than by attempting to do so in a comment.  Other readers may have the same question but miss your explanatory comment. 2. Peter was informed by SO that a comment had been left on his question, but I was not. (I just happened to notice it.) For me to be notified you need to include "@CarySwoveland" (or just "Cary" preceded by the ampersand). Comments can have at most one ampersand-username.

Answer (score 0):

i figured since the "o" is a fix character in the sequence to be accepted, i can just go through with a count var and see if the characters next to it are equal to each other and non-vowels. also i found that slice can be also passed two parameters so that it slices starting at an offset and stopping after the given length.

```
index = 0
  while index < str.length
    index = index + 1
    if str[index] == "o" and str[index-1] == str[index+1] and str[index-1] != /[^aeiou]/ 
      str.slice!(index, 2)
```